# Graphing longitude and latitude points on image distorts matplotlib plot

Tags: python, numpy, google-maps, matplotlib, imshow

I need help understanding why the two plots shown do not have the same aspect ratio.

Using the first block of code I get a printed mesh rectangle of points.

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplolib.pyplot as plt


    xmin = 36.705841363768116
    xmax = 36.99569643623188
    ymin = -76.50505225020194
    ymax = -76.06669294979804
    X = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 25)
    Y = np.linspace(ymax, ymin, 25)
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
    fig= plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(xx, yy, ls='None', marker='.')
    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
    plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
    plt.show()
```

[image: Numpy Matplotlib Meshgrid]

However using very similar code I get a significantly distorted image over the original image which is a square.

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplolib.pyplot as plt

    X = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 25)
    Y = np.linspace(ymax, ymin, 25)
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
    fig= plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    BBox = (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
    map_sq = plt.imread('..\map2.png')
    ax.plot(xx, yy, ls='None', marker='.',  zorder=1, alpha= 0.2, c='b')
    ax.set_title('Plotting Spatial Data on Map')
    ax.set_xlim(BBox[0],BBox[1])
    ax.set_ylim(BBox[2],BBox[3])
    ax.imshow(map_sq, zorder=0, extent = BBox, aspect= 'equal')
    plt.savefig('..\map_plot2.png')
    plt.show()
```

[image: Numpy Meshgrid over map]

The reason I am doing this is to visualize all the longitude and latitude points created by the meshgrid. I then am feeding those points to get all of the cities/counties etc within the bounding box using Google Maps API.

Comment: `extent` overrides `aspect`.  Notice in your first plot that the dots are much closer vertically than they are horizontally.  In your second plot, the dots are square.  The problem is, with a map at 36 degrees latitude, the points can't be square.  You may need to adjust the extents to match the map.

Comment: And by the way, you have the axes swapped here.  Virginia Beach is at -76 degrees longitude and +37 degrees latitude.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I will swap the axes. How would I go about adjusting the extend to match the map?  Should I use the highest latitude or a different numerical value?

Comment: Thanks that did it, I appreciate the help, I'm not super familiar with Numpy meshgrid and working with coordinates.